# How can a member know in what class instance it is constructed?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
    class C {
    public
      T x;
    };
```

Is there an elegant way for the constructor of x to know **implicitly** in what instance of C it is constructing?

---

I've implemented such behavior with some dirty inelegant machinery. I need this for my sqlite3 wrapper. I don't like all wrappers I've seen, their API IMO ugly and inconvenient. I want something like this:

```
    class TestRecordset: public Recordset {
    public:
      // The order of fields declarations specifies column index of the field.
      // There is TestRecordset* pointer inside Field class, 
      // but it goes here indirectly  so I don't have to 
      // re-type all the fields in the constructor initializer list.
      Field<__int64> field1;
      Field<wstring> field2;
      Field<double> field3;

      // have TestRecordset* pointer too so only name of parameter is specified
      // in TestRecordset constructor
      Param<wstring> param;

      virtual string get_sql() {
        return "SELECT 1, '1', NULL FROM test_table WHERE param=:PARAM";
      }

      // try & unlock are there because of my dirty tricks.
      // I want to get rid of them.

      TestRecordset(wstring param_value)
      try : Recordset(open_database(L"test.db")), param("PARAM") {
        param = param_value;
       // I LOVE RAII but i cant use it here. 
       // Lock is set in Recordset constructor, 
       // not in TestRecordset constructor.
        unlock(this);
        fetch();
      } catch(...) {
        unlock(this);
        throw;
      }
    };
```

I want to clarify the fact - it is a part of the *working* code. You *can* do this in C++. I just want to do it in a more nice way.

---

I've found a way to get rid of unlock and try block. I've remembered there is such a thing as thread local storage. Now I can write constructor as simple as that:

```
  TestRecordset(wstring param_value): 
    Recordset(open_database(L"test.db")), param("PARAM") {
        param = param_value;
        fetch();
   }
```

---

to dribeas: 
My objective is to avoid redundant and tedious typing. Without some tricks behind the scene I will have to type for each Field and Param:

```
TestRecordset(wstring param_value): Recordset(open_database(L"test.db")), param(this, "PARAM"),
   field1(this, 0), field2(this, 1), field3(this, 2) { ... }
```

It is redundant, ugly and inconvenient. For example, if I'll have to add new field in the
middle of SELECT I'll have to rewrite all the column numbers. 
Some notes on your post:

1. Fields and Params *are* initialized by their default constructors.
2. Order of initializers in constructor is irrelevant. Fields are always initialized in order of their declaration. I've used this fact to track down column index for fields
3. Base classes are constructed first. So when Fields are constructed internal field list in Recordset are ready to use by Filed default constructor.
4. I CAN'T use RAII here. I need to acquire lock in Recorset constructor and release it obligatory in TestRecordset constructor *after all Fields are constructed*.

Comment: I actually wrote an answer complaining about your lack of RAII in the constructor but deleted it afterwards when I noticed the base class constructor call.

Comment: On the other hand, wouldn't it be better to `unlock` in the RecordSet constructor, as well?

Comment: No. I need qcquire lock in Recordset constructor and obligatory release lock in in TestRecordset constructor after all Fileds and Params are constructed.

Comment: if you haven't got a user defined ctor or dtor or private data or anything making it non-pod, you can use the offsetof macro to get the offset within the parent object, and then you can calculate the this pointer of the parent object using that value

Answer (score 8):

No. Objects aren't supposed to need to know where they're being used from in order to work. As far as x is concerned, it's an instance of T. That's it. It doesn't behave differently according to whether it's a member of class C, a member of class D, an automatic, a temporary, etc.

Furthermore, even if the T constructor did know about the instance of C, that instance of C would be incomplete since of course it has not finished construction yet, because its members haven't been constructed. C++ offers you plenty of chances to shoot yourself in the foot, but offering you a reference to an incomplete object in another class's constructor isn't one of them.

The only thing I can think of to approximate your code example is to do something like

```
#define INIT_FIELDS field1(this), field2(this), field3(this)
```

immediately after the list of fields, then use INIT_FIELDS in the initializer list and #undef it. It's still duplication, but at least it's all in one place. This will probably surprise your colleagues, however.

The other way to make sure you don't forget a field is to remove the zero-arg constructor from Field. Again, you still have to do the typing, but at least if you forget something the compiler will catch it. The non-DRY nature of initializer lists is, I think, something C++ just has to live with.

Comment: No-No-No, this #define is <i>ugly</i>

Comment: Of course, but it's an ugly problem: "how do I not type the stuff I have to type in order for C++ to do what I want?". I didn't say I thought it was a good idea, I said I thought it was the closest I could think of. What I'd do is what I say in the last para.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, C++ initializer syntax is ugly too, but that doesn't mean nobody uses it ;-)

Comment: I disagree with your phrase "have to type". Your don't have to. Your have to pay some, but it is possible to implement such a behavior. My code that I quote in question is a part of a working code.

Comment: Well, one hack I can think of is for the constructor of RecordSet to store "this" in a global, and the constructor of Field to read it and cast it to TestRecordSet*. I call it a hack because I don't like designing for thread-non-safety: is that what the lock's for?

Comment: Ah, just seen your edit to the question about TLS, so I guess that is what you're doing. Fair enough: it's still not re-entrant but then I doubt you'd ever need it to be. Assuming Field isn't used anywhere else it gets the job done, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to One by One's answer, the actual question you should be asking is: "what is wrong with my solution design that it requires objects to know where they are instanciated?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

Out of pure curiosity, why should it matter ? do you have a context in which this can be useful?

M.

Answer (score 0):

I experiment with things like this in C# all the time - I use reflection to do it.

Consider getting a reflection or code generation library for C++ to help you do what you want to.

Now, I can't tell you how to find a good reflection or code generation library for C++, but that's a different question!

Comment: Reflection is too costly. I better of with what I've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in your code. You comment that all fields plus the param attribute have pointers back into the TestRecordSet but that they don't need to be initialized? Or is it the object of the question, how to avoid having to pass the this pointers during construction?

If what you want is avoid adding all fields in the initialization list of your constructor, then it is a flawed objective. You should always initialize all your members in the initialization list and do so in the same order that they are declared in the class (this is not language enforced, but more of a globally learnt experience).

Your use of the try constructor block is just about he only recommended usage for that functionality (Anyone interested read [GOTW#66](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm)) if it is indeed required. If the RecordSet member has been constructed (and thus the lock acquired) and something goes wrong afterwards in the constructor then [see quote below] the RecordSet will be destroyed and if it uses RAII internally it will free the lock, so I believe that the try/catch may not really be required.

C++03, 15.2 Exception Handling / Constructors and destructors

> An object that is partially
>   constructed or partially destroyed
>   will have destructors executed for all
>   of its fully constructed subobjects,
>   that is, for subobjects for which the
>   constructor has completed execution
>   and the destructor has not yet begun
>   execution.